# Why can't I sort an array of strings by `count`?

Tags: ruby, string, sorting

With this code:

```
line = ("Ignore punctuation, please :)")

string = line.strip.downcase.split(//)
string.select! {|x| /[a-z]/.match(x) }
string.sort_by!{ |x| string.count(x)}
```

the result is:

```
["r", "g", "s", "l", "c", "o", "o", "p", "u", "i", "t", "u", "a", "t", "i", "a", "p", "n", "e", "e", "n", "n", "e"]
```

Does sorting by count not work in this case? Why? Is there a better way to isolate the words by frequency?

Comment: The output actually is sorted, in ascending order (with ties coming in any order between themselves). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Say the string is "abcbabebd" it should sort to something similar to [c, d, e, a, a, b, b, b, b] where the least repeated elements are first and then the more repeated elements are last @Cameron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your comment, I suppose that you want to sort characters by frequency and alphabetically. When the only `sort_by!` criteria is `string.count(x)`, frequency groups with the same number of characters can appear mixed with each other. To sort each group alphabetically you have to add a second criteria in the `sort_by!` method:

```
line = ("Ignore punctuation, please :)")

string = line.strip.downcase.split(//)
string.select! {|x| /[a-z]/.match(x) }
string.sort_by!{ |x| [string.count(x), x]}
```

Then the output will be

```
["c", "g", "l", "r", "s", "a", "a", "i", "i", "o", "o", "p", "p", "t", "t", "u", "u", "e", "e", "e", "n", "n", "n"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your code line-by-line.

```
line = ("Ignore punctuation, please :)")
s = line.strip.downcase
  #=> "ignore punctuation, please :)"
```

There's no particular reason to `strip` here, as you will be removing spaces and punctuation later anyway.

```
string = s.split(//)
  #=> ["i", "g", "n", "o", "r", "e", " ", "p", "u", "n", "c", "t",
  #    "u", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", ",", " ", "p", "l", "e", "a",
  #    "s", "e", " ", ":", ")"]
```

You've chosen to split the sentence into characters, which is fine, but as I'll mention at the end, you could just use `String` methods. In any case,

```
string = s.chars
```

does the same thing and is arguably more clear. What you have now is an array named `string`. Isn't that a bit confusing? Let's instead call it `arr`:

```
arr = s.chars
```

(One often sees `s` and `str` for names of strings, `a` and `arr` for names of arrays, `h` and `hash` for names of hashes, and so on.)

```
arr.select! {|x| /[a-z]/.match(x) }
  #=> ["i", "g", "n", "o", "r", "e", "p", "u", "n", "c", "t", "u",
  #    "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", "p", "l", "e", "a", "s", "e"]
```

Now you've eliminated all but lowercase letters. You could also write that:

```
arr.select! {|x| s =~ /[a-z]/ }
```

or

```
arr.select! {|x| s[/[a-z]/] }
```

You are now ready to sort.

```
arr.sort_by!{ |x| arr.count(x) }
  #=> ["l", "g", "s", "c", "r", "i", "p", "u", "a", "o", "t", "p",
  #    "a", "t", "i", "o", "u", "n", "n", "e", "e", "n", "e"]
```

This is OK, but it's not good practice to be sorting an array in place and counting the frequency of its elements at the same time. Better would be:

```
arr1 = arr.sort_by{ |x| arr.count(x) }
```

which gives the same ordering. Is the resulting sorted array correct? Let's count the number of times each letter appears in the string.

I will create a hash whose keys are the unique elements of `arr` and whose values are the number of times the associated key appears in `arr`. There are a few ways to do this. A simple but not very efficient way is as follows:

```
h = {}
a = arr.uniq
  #=> ["l", "g", "s", "c", "r", "i", "p", "u", "a", "o", "t", "n", "e"]
a.each { |c| h[c] = arr.count(c) }
h #=> {"l"=>1, "g"=>1, "s"=>1, "c"=>1, "r"=>1, "i"=>2, "p"=>2,
  #    "u"=>2, "a"=>2, "o"=>2, "t"=>2, "n"=>3, "e"=>3}
```

This would normally be written:

```
h = arr.uniq.each_with_object({}) { |c,h| h[c] = arr.count(c) }
```

The elements of `h` are in increasing order of value, but that's just coincidence.  To ensure they are in that order (to make it easier to see the order), we would need to construct an array, sort it, then convert it to a hash:

```
a = arr.uniq.map { |c| [c, arr.count(c)] }
  #=> [["l", 1], ["g", 1], ["s", 1], ["c", 1], ["r", 1], ["a", 2], ["p", 2],
  #    ["u", 2], ["i", 2], ["o", 2], ["t", 2], ["n", 3], ["e", 3]] 
a = a.sort_by { |_,count| count }
  #=> [["l", 1], ["g", 1], ["s", 1], ["c", 1], ["r", 1], ["a", 2], ["t", 2],
  #    ["u", 2], ["i", 2], ["o", 2], ["p", 2], ["n", 3], ["e", 3]] 
h = Hash[a]
  #=> {"l"=>1, "g"=>1, "s"=>1, "c"=>1, "r"=>1, "i"=>2, "t"=>2,
  #    "u"=>2, "a"=>2, "o"=>2, "p"=>2, "n"=>3, "e"=>3}
```

One would normally see this written:

```
h = Hash[arr.uniq.map { |c| [c, arr.count(c)] }.sort_by(&:last)]
```

or, in Ruby v2.0+:

```
h = arr.uniq.map { |c| [c, arr.count(c)] }.sort_by(&:last).to_h
```

Note that, prior to Ruby 1.9, there was no concept of key ordering in hashes.

The values of `h`'s key-value pairs show that your sort is correct. It is not, however, very efficient. That's because in:

```
arr.sort_by { |x| arr.count(x) }
```

you repeatedly traverse `arr`, counting frequencies of elements. It's better to construct the hash above:

```
h = arr.uniq.each_with_object({}) { |c,h| h[c] = arr.count(c) }
```

before performing the sort, then:

```
arr.sort_by { |x| h[x] }
```

As an aside, let me mention a more efficient way to construct the hash `h`, one which requires only a single pass through `arr`:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
arr.each { |x| h[x] += 1 }
h #=> {"l"=>1, "g"=>1, "s"=>1, "c"=>1, "r"=>1, "a"=>2, "p"=>2,
  #    "u"=>2, "i"=>2, "o"=>2, "t"=>2, "n"=>3, "e"=>3}
```

or, more succinctly:

```
h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x,h| h[x] += 1 }
```

Here `h` is called a *counting hash*:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

creates an empty hash whose default value is zero. This means that if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` will return zero. The [abbreviated assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment) `h[c] += 1` expands to:

```
h[c] = h[c] + 1
```

and if `h` does not have a key `c`, the default value is assigned to `h[c]` on the right side:

```
h[c] = 0 + 1 #=> 1
```

but the next time `c` is encountered:

```
h[c] = h[c] + 1
  #=> 1 + 1 => 2
```

Lastly, let's start over and do as much as we can with `String` methods:

```
line = ("Ignore punctuation, please :)")
s = line.strip.downcase.gsub(/./) { |c| (c =~ /[a-z]/) ? c : '' }
  #=> "ignorepunctuationplease"
h = s.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> {"i"=>2, "g"=>1, "n"=>3, "o"=>2, "r"=>1, "e"=>3, "p"=>2,
  #    "u"=>2, "c"=>1, "t"=>2, "a"=>2, "l"=>1, "s"=>1}
s.each_char.sort_by { |c| h[c] }
  #=> ["l", "g", "s", "c", "r", "i", "p", "u", "a", "o", "t", "p",
  #    "a", "t", "i", "o", "u", "n", "n", "e", "e", "n", "e"]
```